# Fetch partial document

Tags: rethinkdb

Is it possible to fetch specific parts of a document in RethinkDB? For instance:

```
// Doesn't retrieve the password field
r.db("test").get("some-id", { "password": false }).run()
```

I'm looking for a feature that is similar to how the [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) argument works in MongoDB's db.find().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! The commands I was looking for were [pluck](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/pluck/) and [without](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/without/).